# Task Scheduler Tasks Running at the Same Time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

We have multiple standard tasks on the task scheduler that calls an application with a parameter. The tasks run at different hours of the morning. However, in the last few days all the tasks have started to trigger of the same time, with a "due to time trigger condition". So now all tasks are running later than usual. We have tried different users and settings and end up with the same result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
 <Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
<RegistrationInfo>
<Date>2015-07-23T12:32:22.8884306</Date>
<Author>SOUTHAFRICA\User</Author>
<Description>Package</Description>
</RegistrationInfo>
<Triggers>
<CalendarTrigger>
  <StartBoundary>2018-04-11T06:02:30</StartBoundary>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
  <ScheduleByWeek>
    <DaysOfWeek>
      <Monday />
      <Tuesday />
      <Wednesday />
      <Thursday />
      <Friday />
    </DaysOfWeek>
    <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
  </ScheduleByWeek>
</CalendarTrigger>
</Triggers>
<Principals>
<Principal id="Author">
  <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
  <UserId>SOUTHAFRICA\User</UserId>
  <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
</Principal>
</Principals>
<Settings>
<IdleSettings>
  <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
  <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
</IdleSettings>
<MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
<DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
<StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
<AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
<StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
<RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
<AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
<Enabled>false</Enabled>
<Hidden>false</Hidden>
<RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
<WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
<ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
<Priority>7</Priority>
</Settings>
<Actions Context="Author">
 <Exec>
   <Command>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Application.exe"</Command>
   <Arguments>62</Arguments>
 </Exec>
</Actions>
```

Comment: Can you disclose the Task Scheduler job settings of one of the jobs to start with that is affected by this that you describe? Screen shots of the GUI settings of the task or an XML export perhaps if you know how .

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: From the Trigger when you go to edit it and get the `Edit Trigger` windows, in the **Settings** section either check or uncheck the `Synchronize across time zones` and see if that helps. Otherwise do you see it being a problem to `Run with highest privileges` and typing in the username and password for it to execute as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a third party anti virus update, created a scheduled task with a trigger of a random delay of 8 hours. So could potentially offset the time of the other scheduled tasks. This is a bug in windows server 2008.

[Microsoft Bug Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/982341/scheduled-tasks-are-delayed-in-windows-server-2008-or-in-windows-vista)